# Dynamically load WPF View & View Model from DLL

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, user-controls, .net-assembly

I have a wizard created in WPF consisting of pages as `UserControl` objects. What I'm trying to do is to load plugins from .DLL files which contain the following:

- A code file for the plugin logic.
- A XAML user control which will present configuration options for the plugin, displayed in the main wizard.
- A view model for the user control.

I've been able to successfully load in and instantiate the `UserControl` object as well as the View Model, and I have gotten to the stage where the Control appears in it's own wizard page as intended.
(This is probably the view model that's instantiated correctly, since I set the title for the wizard page in the view model and that all works fine)

The problem I'm getting is that the `UserControl` I've loaded from the DLL isn't displaying correctly. Instead of displaying the `UserControl` contents, it just shows the plaintext `MyDLL.MyCustomUserControl` from the line `x:Class="MyDLL.MyCustomUserControl"` where the actual user control should be.

The contents of my user control that I'm loading from the DLL is:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyDLL.MyCustomUserControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<StackPanel>
    <Label Content="This is the Plugin Options Page" />
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=PluginStringText}" />
</StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

The property `PluginStringText` exists in the View Model for this `User Control`.

I have a feeling I need to somehow assign or bind the View Model to the User Control after loading it in from the DLL.
As part of my wizard, there is a section where I define Data Templates (this is another UserControl which contains the Wizard's pages), but I don't know how to actually add extra templates during runtime. I have a feeling this is causing the issue.

Searching through many topics reveals I could probably do this through the code behind file for the view, but then I have no way of obtaining a reference to the view's code behind in the first place to call a method. Is there a way of adding a new DataTemplate entry from the View's View Model class?

```
<UserControl.Resources>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:ExistingPage1ViewModel}">
        <view:ExistingPage1View />
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:ExistingPage2ViewModel}">
        <view:ExistingPage2View />
    </DataTemplate>
<...>
```

Thanks in advance if someone could point me in the right direction

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a way to resolve this.
The problem was as I had expected, there was no mapping between the ViewModel data type and the View in which to render the ViewModel with.

I discovered a useful guide here http://www.ikriv.com/dev/wpf/DataTemplateCreation/ which explains how to create a new data template within code, very similar to if you'd hard coded the template in the XAML.

This was all well and good, but I still had to find a way to call the method to create the data template.

Well - It turned out I didn't need to call the method at all in the code behind! I just put the method to create the data template directly in my view model which is responsible for populating the wizard's pages.

This also has the added benefit that I do not have to hard code my existing pages datatemplate's in the xaml.

---

I will add the code referenced at http://www.ikriv.com/dev/wpf/DataTemplateCreation/ for future reference:

**The method to create the `DataTemplate` object:**

```
DataTemplate CreateTemplate(Type viewModelType, Type viewType)
{
    const string xamlTemplate = "<DataTemplate DataType=\"{{x:Type vm:{0}}}\"><v:{1} /></DataTemplate>";
    var xaml = String.Format(xamlTemplate, viewModelType.Name, viewType.Name, viewModelType.Namespace, viewType.Namespace);

    var context = new ParserContext();

    context.XamlTypeMapper = new XamlTypeMapper(new string[0]);
    context.XamlTypeMapper.AddMappingProcessingInstruction("vm", viewModelType.Namespace, viewModelType.Assembly.FullName);
    context.XamlTypeMapper.AddMappingProcessingInstruction("v", viewType.Namespace, viewType.Assembly.FullName);

    context.XmlnsDictionary.Add("", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation");
    context.XmlnsDictionary.Add("x", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml");
    context.XmlnsDictionary.Add("vm", "vm");
    context.XmlnsDictionary.Add("v", "v");

    var template = (DataTemplate)XamlReader.Parse(xaml, context);
    return template;
}
```

This `DataTemplate` then needs to be registered as an application resource:

**Registering the DataTemplate:**

```
Application.Current.Resources.Add(template.DataTemplateKey;, template);
```

Once again, this code was provided thanks to Ivan Krivyakov at http://www.ikriv.com/dev/wpf/DataTemplateCreation/